# How can we measure the accuracy of prediction algorithm?

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms

We have created a prediction algorithm, which predicts the chances of confirmation of ticket based on some parameters, and gives the prediction in percent.

Now, how do I measure how close the prediction is to reality. Like 70% chances actually mean 70% chance. I would like to have some information, any information to measure the accuracy of this algorithm.

Edit: To clarify, the way our algorithm works is, a user enters his ticket number for any flight or train, and based on historical data with similar situation, we predict the chances of confirmation. So, it's not like there is a fixed number of tickets, but yes we have historical data of various predictions and final result.

Comment: You want to test whether your prediction algorithm is well calibrated. See the following academic papers for ways to do this: http://ssrn.com/abstract=2571710 and http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0297.2012.02561.x/full (gated, didn't find an ungated version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given nowhere near enough information about your
data for me to give you a definitive answer. So I will fill
in the missing blanks with what I suppose is a plausible
scenario, and show you a way to handle that. If the result
is useless, at least you will have a clue how you need
to edit your question so someone can try to give a more
useful answer.

I suppose you have very many tickets, perhaps $n = 1000.$
Also, that your predictions as to likelihood of confirmation
either are give to the nearest ten percent (0.1), or can
be rounded to the nearest 10 percent without terrible loss
of information.

Then suppose you have  ten categories with predictions: $p_i = .1, .2, \dots, 1.0$, for $ i = 1, 2, \dots, 10.$ Then the
respective 'expected' numbers of of confirmations by
category are $E_i = np_i/\sum_{i=1}^{10} p_i$, where the $E_i$ add to $n$.
Also, you should be able to determine the actual numbers
of confirmations in $X_i$ in each category. For example,
of those predicted to be in your 70% category, the predicted
number of confirmations is $E_7$ and the actual number is $X_7.$
For each of the 10 categories, compute $C_i = (E_i - X_i)^2/E_i.$
Then find $Q = C_1 + C_2 + \cdots C_{10}.$

In the circumstances described, if your algorithm is working
very well, then $Q \sim Chisq(df = 9)$, approximately.
The bigger $Q$ the worse your  algorithm is. On average,
if the algorithm is working well then $Q \approx 9$. 
If $Q > 16.92$, then you would say your algorithm isn't
giving predictions that fit with actual observations on
confirmations. (The number is 16.92 is obtained from tables
of the chi-squared distribution: row 9 and column headed '.05',
for a typical printed table.)

This process works OK provided most of the $E_i > 5$ and
all $E_i > 3.$ If that is not the case, merge a couple
of neighboring categories (add the $E_i$s and also add
the $X_i$s). Then instead of $df = 9$ for the chi-squared
distribution you have $df$ equal to one less than the number
of categories after merging. If $n$ is a thousand or so
and the categories are all represented reasonably often,
you should not have to do any mergers.

If you don't get a good fit, you can get some idea for
which percentage prediction categories your algorithm
is working most badly. Those would be the categories
with the largest $C_i$'s. In any case, pay particular
attention to any category $i$ with a $C_i$ greater than 3 or 4.

This method is called a 'Chi-squared Goodness-of-Fit' procedure,
and maybe you want to read about it in a statistics book or online.

Here is an example with data for 1000 tickets simulated according to an
algorithm that is working well;  $Q = 10.4 < 16.9,$ so
the test verifies that the algorithm is OK.

```
   i   p        E   X        C
   1 0.1  18.1818  20 0.181818
   2 0.2  36.3636  28 1.923636
   3 0.3  54.5455  45 1.670455
   4 0.4  72.7273  79 0.541023
   5 0.5  90.9091  82 0.873091
   6 0.6 109.0909 125 2.320076
   7 0.7 127.2727 127 0.000584
   8 0.8 145.4546 159 1.261420
   9 0.9 163.6364 148 1.494141
  10 1.0 181.8182 187 0.147682
```

Comment: Hi Bruce, Thanks a lot for your answer! It certainly is very helpful. There are some clarifications I have made in edit. Basically, we don't have the fixed number of tickets. But we do have the historical data. I think we can still apply the chi-squared procedure on this?

Comment: Also, I have another question regarding chi-squared test. If instead of taking all the C's together and df 9, can I take df 1 and perform test on one case only? Like for C (1.49) and p=0.9 only..

Comment: If you collapsed the table to get two rows (categories), '.09' and 'all else', then you would have df = 2 - 1 = 1. As for your first question, didn't you use 'historical' information to get the predictions of your algorithm?

Comment: What I mean is, based on users who are trying this algorithm, it is possible that 100 users from different trains try this algorithm and for all 100 (since their ticket is confirmed) they get p = 1.0.. Or a similar scenario where users from different trains try and all get p = 0.9.. So the way I was thinking of implementing this was, for p = 0.9 , E = 0.9 * 200 = 180, and then check how many among 200 actually got confirmed later and that would be my X.. But as you can see, this is for p = 0.9 only.. What will be df in this?

Comment: OK, I think I get it.. In the case I mentioned above, there would be two rows, 0.9 and all else.. and in all else both E and X would be 0, so df would become 2-1 = 1

Comment: Just one more question, what is more feasible? To get the Q values for each of 10 rows, and then analyse or like the way you mentioned? What is the difference?

Comment: Must get one Q for the whole table. Relevant value for a row is C.